# RECUPERAR UN FICHERO DE CONTROL MEDIANTE UN FICHERO TRAZA RESETLOG

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

He generado un fichero de control traza llamado micontrol.sql y a partir de él genero el fichero de control reseteando los redologs.

El fichero de control micontrol.sql tendría el siguiente aspecto, y me quedaría con la parte de   Set #2. RESETLOGS case

```
-- The following are current System-scope REDO Log Archival related
-- parameters and can be included in the database initialization file.
--
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST=''
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DUPLEX_DEST=''
--
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_FORMAT=%t_%s_%r.dbf
--
-- DB_UNIQUE_NAME="CICLOX"
--
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_CONFIG='SEND, RECEIVE, NODG_CONFIG'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_MAX_PROCESSES=4
-- STANDBY_FILE_MANAGEMENT=MANUAL
-- STANDBY_ARCHIVE_DEST=?/dbs/arch
-- FAL_CLIENT=''
-- FAL_SERVER=''
--
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='LOCATION=USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='MANDATORY NOREOPEN NODELAY'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='ARCH NOAFFIRM EXPEDITE NOVERIFY SYNC'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='NOREGISTER NOALTERNATE NODEPENDENCY'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='NOMAX_FAILURE NOQUOTA_SIZE NOQUOTA_USED NODB_UNIQUE_NAME'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='VALID_FOR=(PRIMARY_ROLE,ONLINE_LOGFILES)'
-- LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_1=ENABLE

--
-- Below are two sets of SQL statements, each of which creates a new
-- control file and uses it to open the database. The first set opens
-- the database with the NORESETLOGS option and should be used only if
-- the current versions of all online logs are available. The second
-- set opens the database with the RESETLOGS option and should be used
-- if online logs are unavailable.
-- The appropriate set of statements can be copied from the trace into
-- a script file, edited as necessary, and executed when there is a
-- need to re-create the control file.
--
--     Set #1. NORESETLOGS case
--
-- The following commands will create a new control file and use it
-- to open the database.
-- Data used by Recovery Manager will be lost.
-- Additional logs may be required for media recovery of offline
-- Use this only if the current versions of all online logs are
-- available.

-- After mounting the created controlfile, the following SQL
-- statement will place the database in the appropriate
-- protection mode:
--  ALTER DATABASE SET STANDBY DATABASE TO MAXIMIZE PERFORMANCE

STARTUP NOMOUNT
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "CICLOX" NORESETLOGS  ARCHIVELOG
    MAXLOGFILES 16
    MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
    MAXDATAFILES 100
    MAXINSTANCES 8
    MAXLOGHISTORY 292
LOGFILE
  GROUP 1 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo01.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo01a.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  GROUP 2 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo02.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/rddo02a.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  GROUP 3 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo03.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo03s.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512
-- STANDBY LOGFILE
DATAFILE
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/system01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/sysaux01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/undotbs01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/users01.dbf',
  '/Ora2/datos/personal1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/gestor1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/gestor2.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/datos1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/datos2.ora',
  '/Ora2/marzo/examen1.ora',
  '/Ora2/repaso/examen2.ora'
CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
;

-- Commands to re-create incarnation table
-- Below log names MUST be changed to existing filenames on
-- disk. Any one log file from each branch can be used to
-- re-create incarnation records.
-- ALTER DATABASE REGISTER LOGFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/CICLOX/archivelog/2021_05_11/o1_mf_1_1_%u_.arc';
-- ALTER DATABASE REGISTER LOGFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/CICLOX/archivelog/2021_05_11/o1_mf_1_1_%u_.arc';
-- Recovery is required if any of the datafiles are restored backups,
-- or if the last shutdown was not normal or immediate.
RECOVER DATABASE

-- All logs need archiving and a log switch is needed.
ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG ALL;

-- Database can now be opened normally.
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

-- Commands to add tempfiles to temporary tablespaces.
-- Online tempfiles have complete space information.
-- Other tempfiles may require adjustment.
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/temp01.dbf'
     SIZE 30408704  REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 655360  MAXSIZE 32767M;
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMPORAL ADD TEMPFILE '/Ora2/datos/tempo.tmp'
     SIZE 2097152  REUSE AUTOEXTEND OFF;
-- End of tempfile additions.
--
--     Set #2. RESETLOGS case
--
-- The following commands will create a new control file and use it
-- to open the database.
-- Data used by Recovery Manager will be lost.
-- The contents of online logs will be lost and all backups will
-- be invalidated. Use this only if online logs are damaged.

-- After mounting the created controlfile, the following SQL
-- statement will place the database in the appropriate
-- protection mode:
--  ALTER DATABASE SET STANDBY DATABASE TO MAXIMIZE PERFORMANCE

STARTUP NOMOUNT
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "CICLOX" RESETLOGS  ARCHIVELOG
    MAXLOGFILES 16
    MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
    MAXDATAFILES 100
    MAXINSTANCES 8
    MAXLOGHISTORY 292
LOGFILE
  GROUP 1 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo01.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo01a.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  GROUP 2 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo02.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/rddo02a.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  GROUP 3 (
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo03.log',
    '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/redo03s.rdo'
  ) SIZE 50M BLOCKSIZE 512
-- STANDBY LOGFILE
DATAFILE
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/system01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/sysaux01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/undotbs01.dbf',
  '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/users01.dbf',
  '/Ora2/datos/personal1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/gestor1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/gestor2.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/datos1.ora',
  '/Ora2/datos/datos2.ora',
  '/Ora2/marzo/examen1.ora',
  '/Ora2/repaso/examen2.ora'
CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
;

-- Commands to re-create incarnation table
-- Below log names MUST be changed to existing filenames on
-- disk. Any one log file from each branch can be used to
-- re-create incarnation records.
-- ALTER DATABASE REGISTER LOGFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/CICLOX/archivelog/2021_05_11/o1_mf_1_1_%u_.arc';
-- ALTER DATABASE REGISTER LOGFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/CICLOX/archivelog/2021_05_11/o1_mf_1_1_%u_.arc';
-- Recovery is required if any of the datafiles are restored backups,
-- or if the last shutdown was not normal or immediate.
RECOVER DATABASE USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE

-- Database can now be opened zeroing the online logs.
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;

-- Commands to add tempfiles to temporary tablespaces.
-- Online tempfiles have complete space information.
-- Other tempfiles may require adjustment.
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/Ora1/app/oracle/oradata/CICLOX/temp01.dbf'
     SIZE 30408704  REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 655360  MAXSIZE 32767M;
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMPORAL ADD TEMPFILE '/Ora2/datos/tempo.tmp'
     SIZE 2097152  REUSE AUTOEXTEND OFF;
-- End of tempfile additions.
--
```

A continuación, desde la consola de SQLPLUS inicio la recuperación mediante
SQL> @'/Ora2/copias/micontrol.sql';
No obstante, me aparecen los siguientes errores al hacerlo reseteando los redologs. Si lo hago sin resetear los redologs no tengo ningún problema, pero me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal.
Dejo a continuación los errores:

```
SQL> @'/Ora2/copias/micontrol.sql';
Instancia ORACLE iniciada.

Total System Global Area  839282688 bytes
Fixed Size          2233000 bytes
Variable Size         587205976 bytes
Database Buffers      247463936 bytes
Redo Buffers            2379776 bytes

Archivo de control creado.

ORA-00279: el cambio 1294101 generado en 05/11/2021 13:29:54 es necesario para
el thread 1
ORA-00289: sugerencia:
/Ora1/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/CICLOX/archivelog/2021_05_13/o1_mf_1_17_%u_.
arc
ORA-00280: el cambio 1294101 para el thread 1 esta en la secuencia numero 17


ORA-00308: no se puede abrir el archive log 'ALTER'
ORA-27037: no se ha podido obtener el estado del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3


ORA-00308: no se puede abrir el archive log 'ALTER'
ORA-27037: no se ha podido obtener el estado del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3


ORA-00308: no se puede abrir el archive log 'SIZE'
ORA-27037: no se ha podido obtener el estado del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3


ORA-00308: no se puede abrir el archive log 'ALTER'
ORA-27037: no se ha podido obtener el estado del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3


ORA-00308: no se puede abrir el archive log 'SIZE'
ORA-27037: no se ha podido obtener el estado del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3


Especificar log: {<RET>=sugerido | nombre_archivo | AUTO | CANCEL}
```

Comment: Por favor, publica tu script y el resultado como texto, no como imágenes. Dale clic en Editar para cambiarlo. Si no tienes completo el conjunto de archivos que se necesita para realizar la recuperación, agrega `until cancel` a la sentencia `recover`, eso dejará la base lo más actualizada posible.

Comment: No entiendo lo que me comentas del script. Se refiere a que publique el script micontrol.sql como texto y los errores también? Gracias!

Comment: @jachguate tengo el log.xml, le serviría?

Comment: Si, @Patricia, en StackOverflow las imágenes suelen considerarse una forma inadecuada de publicar información que puede ponerse como texto plano en una pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: Las razones están expuestas en muchos lugares, por ejemplo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21

Comment: @jachguate De acuerdo, muchas gracias y perdona. Lo estoy modificando

Comment: @jachguate ya estaría modificado. El fichero log.xml no lo puedo poner porque es demasiado largo, pero he puesto el script de micontrol y los errores que me han aparecido en la consola sqlplus